# Facebook Graph API List pages where I'm a "Live Contributor" Role

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

using this graph api endpoint :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/accounts?access_token={access-token}
```

I'm able to list all **the pages** where I'm **admin** or **pages that I created myself**
however I'm not able to list pages where I have the "**live contributor**" role.
Anyone has an Idea about how to list all the pages where I'm :

1. creator
2. admin
3. live contributor?

Thanks !

ps : the live contributor role is to permit any user to create **live video** stream on the facebook page.

I opened a bug with facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/348860552221613/

I'll let you updated.

Comment: if it does not show up with the manage_pages permission, then it will most likely not show up at all. live contributors don´t actually "manage" the pages, i guess.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my app got approuved for : manage_pages, publish_pages, business_management + basic scopes as email, public_profile and user_friends